# previous element's CSS hover state doesn't go away after set focus on other element

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, focus

**Issue Details (Can be replicate on Safari Version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7), Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100, Opera 48.0, IE Edge. Except Firefox 55.0.3 - it works fine as expected described below):**

When I mouse over the "Set focus to some field" button

And I clicked the button

Then it set focus on "some-text-field" input element

And the button will float to right

And my mouse no longer hover on top of the button anymore as it moved away

And button's hover state stays and not going away

When i move my mouse

Then I see the "Set focus to some field" button's hover state go away

**Expected results:**

> When I mouse over the "Set focus to some field" button
>
> And I clicked the button
>
> Then it set focus on "some-text-field" input element
>
> And button's hover state stays should go away
>
> And I should not need to move my mouse to get rid of the button's
>   hover state

**What have i tried and still doesn't work?**

1. setTimeout 1 second delay to set focus
2. setTimeout 1 second delay to set button class to float right
3. set button blur() after 1 second delay

Code:

```js
var someTextFieldEl = document.getElementById('some-text-field')

document.getElementById('btn-setfocus').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('float-right')
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('float-right')) {
    someTextFieldEl.focus()
  }
})
```

```css
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="some-text-field">Some Field</label>
        <input id="some-text-field" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
      <button id="btn-setfocus" class="btn btn-primary offset-md-9" type="button">Set focus to some field</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSbin Link](http://jsbin.com/rozipidage/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: if the mouse is hover the button, then that the hover states remains is absolutely normal. Do you really want to get rid of it ?

Comment: shouldn't be the hover state stays only when the mouse is still hover on top of the button? because after clicked the button, it then floats to right, which means the mouse position will no longer be hover on top of the button anymore, and the hover state should be gone. And the focus has been successfully set to the text field, but the button's hover state still stays until you move your mouse (and again your mouse shouldn't be hover on top of the button anymore cause the button has moved / shifted to the right)

Comment: sorry, did not noticed the button was moving. My firefox(56) seems to behave fine though, hover state is not triggered once button floats . **Give a try** to position or transform **to force a reflow** at screen of the componment https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zEybNq

Comment: As mentioned above, Firefox has been tested working fine. Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE Edge not working.

Comment: okay, what about forcing the reflow ... did you test the codepen linked to play with and check behavior ? transform or position:relative; should repaint the element & update calculation of where it is suppose to stand (obviously not under the mouse anymore)... if in these words it makes any sense.... creating a pseudo after or before might also do something about it. How ever the codepen link earlier did not show the issue you describe nor in IE, nor in Chrome or Opera (counter view only shows the test i have made, obviously you did not check it out .... )

Comment: hi G-Cyr, i've actually tried your codepen link before and it doesn't work. if you don't move your mouse after u click the button then it shift and set focus. You'll see what i mean (try on chrome or any browsers mentioned above except firefox).

Also i've also made another example to demostrate your suggestions doesn't work. I've made the hover background color sharper for easier to identify the issue:
http://jsbin.com/deyavacibe/edit?html,js,output